# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'SetuptoolsVersion' and 'SetuptoolsVersion'

Tags: python, google-api

I'm using Google NLP API and I'm trying to run the entity_sentiment_text function in the snippets.py script (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/language/cloud-client/v1/snippets.py) but I get this error:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'SetuptoolsVersion' and 
'SetuptoolsVersion'
```

Apparently it is raised in _cryptography_rsa.py

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3):

This seems possibly related to your system `pip` installation, [as discussed here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3057). What sort of environment are you in that you are invoking `setuptools`? Are you trying to `pip install` something before running the linked script?

If so, you may try one of the linked solutions, something like this (depending on your system Python and which versions you prefer to use):

```
pip install --ignore-installed pip
```

and then try again.

Answer (score 2):

As discussed [here in this GitHub thread](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5429#issuecomment-570252328) you may need to update/upgrade the pip by:

```
sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

if you are on Ubuntu/Debian, or from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1032408/535800) by

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

for all operating systems (Including Linux distros)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution :

```
conda install -c conda-forge/label/broken setuptools
```